# Restricting codebuild/pipeline access to two buckets, access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild, amazon-iam

Currently with S3Full access, my codebuild works fine. However, when I try to restrict codebuild's access via the listed policy below, I get an error message for the folders in the private repo that I need to access. One of the S3 buckets is the usual codepipeline bucket and the other is a private maven repo that we're hosting (which requires AWS access key).

Here is the IAM policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
"Resource": "*"
},
{
"Action": [
"s3:ListBucket"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc/*",
"arn:aws:s3::: labs-maven-repo"
]
},
{
"Action": [
"s3:*"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc/*",
"arn:aws:s3:::labs-maven-repo"
]
}
]
}
```

Below are the errors I'm getting during the build phase in codebuild. Also what's interesting and may be worth noting is that the folders inside the maven repo are being listed in the error messages below but not the S3 bucket itself.

```
WARNING Could not transfer metadata com.project.metadata:data-model:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to -server name given in settings.xml file- (s3://labs-maven-repo/release): Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; 

WARNING Could not transfer metadata com.project.metadata:data-model:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to -server name given in settings.xml file- (s3://labs-maven-repo/snapshot): Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

P.S. this is one of my first Stack Overflow posts so if there's additional information or anything I can provide please let me know.

Comment: They look like some unusual S3 bucket names: leading and embedded spaces and dashes at both ends. Might be worth checking they conform to the naming conventions: [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

Comment: Ah! I apologize, I was trying to make the bucket names as generic as possible. The dashes were to avoid formatting on another forum! Thank you for pointing that out for me. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving data from the bucket then You just need to add read permission of that bucket in your IAM policy.
If you are uploading data to that bucket then you need to add write permission of that bucket in you IAM policy.
Then please try again.

Answer (score 0):

For s3:ListBucket specify the bucket as the resource without wildcard. So:

> "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc"

instead of

> "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc/*"

For object operations (which you have as s3:*) use

> "arn:aws:s3:::labs-maven-repo/*"

instead of

> "arn:aws:s3:::labs-maven-repo".

For S3, there are three different operations to consider:

1. Operations on all buckets: specify more than one bucket as the resource.

   > E.g. "Resource":"*"
2. Operations on the bucket itself specify the bucket as the resource.

   > E.g. "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc","arn:aws:s3:::labs-maven-repo"]
3. Operations on objects in a bucket specify any prefix of the bucket.

   > E.g. "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-etcetc/*","arn:aws:s3:::labs-maven-repo/*"]